# gui framework for a java game

Tags: java, user-interface

I've written a Java version of the board game Settlers of Catan, and want to make a gui for it(though I've no experience with gui's). 
What are a couple gui's for game creation people recommend?

Comment: So until now your game is text based and now you want to make it a graphical game? Or do you just want to add some menus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 2D Gui's then the Java windowing toolkits such as AWT, SWING, SWT etc. will serve your purpose without too much work. For 3D gui's I recommend [Ardor3D](http://ardor3d.com/) or its parent [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/). For Ui components only you can use [FengGui](http://www.fenggui.org/doku.php).